# Problema na criação do ambiente com django

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

Estou tentando criar um projeto em ambiente virtualizado com a ferramenta virtualwrapper, nesse ambiente instalei o django porém ao tentar criar um projeto com o comando `django-admin startproject meu-projeto` ele não criar os arquivos padrões que são ( mas cria a pasta vazia ) :

### [image: Filder de projeto django]

E apresenta um erro ao rodar o comando de criação ( já citado ) :

> if new_path.endswith(extensions) or filename in extra_files:
>   UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position
>   13: ordinal not in range(128)

Encontrei [esse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21129020/how-to-fix-unicodedecodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-decode-byte) artigo porém acho que não se aplica nesse caso ( pois rodei os comandos e a criação dos arquivos padrões não ocorreu ), alguém sabe como devo proceder para resolver ?

Comment: Qual a versão do Python e Django você está usando?

Comment: python3 e django em sua versão mais recente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontrei esta resposta que parece ter bastante relação com o que você está fazendo, pois nas respostas vi que você está usando python3

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20251562/how-to-install-django-for-python-3-3

Está usando pip3 para instalar os pacotes?

Em tempo, você está tentando criar um projeto com um hífen.
Tentei fazer o mesm outilizando python-2.7 e django 1.10 e recebo a seguinte mensagem:

```
$ django-admin startproject teste-com-hifem
CommandError: 'teste-com-hifem' is not a valid project name. Please use only numbers, letters and underscores.
```

Abraços e bons fontes!

Comment: Vlw, e não estou usando hífem ( só coloquei na pergunta porém na prática coloquei assim : " site " ) ... resolvi thx.

Comment: Curiosidade, qual foi a solução? Abraços!

Comment: Criei outra máquina virtual e instalei o django em sua versão anterior. ( mudei a codificação da nova maquina e reiniciei todos os serviços )